# What i the best way to do Multiplayer server?

Tags: android, sockets, multiplayer

I want to make a multi-player game on android,something small not too fancy,my thought on sending data to other players is sending the coordinates, and for instance only the players that will be close(depends on users screen size) will be updated,but still even only few coordinates to update every time that a player moves will be a lot,And i don't know what is the best way to save players that are currently Online (maybe by hash map)?

Comment: This highly depends on the type of game.

Comment: @FD_ a 2d game,with a view from sky,and every player within a view of a certain player will be shown in his screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way should be to use some existing library.
There are many multi-player game server libraries out there, but since you are asking for something small (and you would probably prefer it being free too), I'd suggest following choices. (All java)

1. [Netty](http://netty.io/) - powerful low level, suitable for even high end purposes, but relatively difficult to start with.
2. [JWebSockets](https://jwebsocket.org/) - All TCP, reliable connection, a great choice if played with for some time.
3. [Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet) - Simple to use, lightweight, not cluttered with many features, might be sufficient for small games without much efforts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that really helps,but which is the best form to save players that are online in the game?

Comment: This is a really trivial problem, and people usually use the concept of 'game rooms', a web search might give you some good glimpses of it. (Players log in to specific room and list of players is maintained by the server, thus facilitating scalability by allowing multiple servers). Good luck.